# Telethon: download channel videos and pictures based on messages' reactions

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to figure out a way to scan through all the unread messages in a Telegram Channel and download videos and images that have more than certain amount of reactions.

I got to the point where the script will download all the unread videos and images, but I am stuck at how to filter those messages based on reactions. For example: only download the videos and images that have at least 3 reactions and/or 3❤️ reactions.

My code is included below. The script downloads all the unread videos and images from the channel `title` and store them in a sub-folder called `title`. Like I said, I don't want to download all the videos and images. I only want the ones that meet certain reaction thresholds. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
title = 'channel name'

with TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    chat_names = client(GetDialogsRequest(
        offset_date=None,
        offset_id=0,
        offset_peer='username',
        limit=0,
        hash=0
    ))

    result = client(functions.messages.GetPeerDialogsRequest(
        peers=[title]
    ))

    for chat in chat_names.chats:
        if chat.title == title:
            for message in client.iter_messages(title, limit=result.dialogs[0].unread_count):
                if message.photo or message.video:
                    message.download_media('./' + str(titles) + '/')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are easier ways to fetch dialogs than using [`GetDialogsRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_dialogs.html), which is raw API, with [`client.get_dialogs`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.get_dialogs) instead:

```py
# Fetch the first 100 dialogs (remove the 100 to fetch all of them)
# I have renamed `chat_names` with `dialogs` to make it clearer.
dialogs = client.get_dialogs(100)
```

The second call to [`GetPeerDialogsRequest`](https://GetPeerDialogsRequest) is also unnecessary. It's meant to be used when you want to fetch dialog information about a particular user or chat - but you already fetched all dialog information before.

(Technically, we could remove `client.get_dialogs` and only use `GetPeerDialogsRequest`, but for simplicity I won't do that.)

To check reactions given a message you can access the `message.reactions` field (as seen in the raw API for [`Message`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/message.html)):

```py
print(message.reactions.stringify())
```

This will give you a feel for what the object looks like with your Telethon version, in my case:

```py
MessageReactions(
    results=[
        ReactionCount(
            reaction=ReactionEmoji(
                emoticon='❤'
            ),
            count=11,
            chosen_order=None
        ),
        ...
    ]
)
```

So all that's left is checking if a message meets your needs. I'll make a separate function to make it easier to read:

```py
def should_download(message):
    if not message.photo or not message.video:
        return False  # no photo or video, no need to download

    if not message.reactions:
        return False  # no reactions

    for reaction in message.reactions.results:
        # It might be a ReactionCustomEmoji which doesn't have an emoticon
        # Use getattr to read the emoticon field or return None if it doesn't exist
        emoticon = getattr(reaction.reaction, 'emoticon', None)
        if emoticon in ('❤', '') and reaction.count >= 3:
            return True  # has enough reactions

    return False  # did not find the reactions we wanted
```

And finally the loop can use the function:

```py
for dialog in dialogs:
    if dialog.title == title:
        # We can use the dialog instead of the title as the chat
        for message in client.iter_messages(dialog, dialog.unread_count):
            if should_download(message):
                message.download_media('./' + str(titles) + '/')
```